# Does JS short-curcuit evaluation work with async/await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, short-circuit-evaluation

It's well known that in this snippet, if `getFirst()` returns truthy value, `getSecond()` is not evaluated:

```
const result = getFirst() || getSecond();
```

However, I'm curious if the same holds for async functions:

```
const result = (await getFirstAsync()) || (await getSyncAsync());
```

Does it launch the second promise, or waits for the first to get resolved first?

Comment: It will await the left-hand-side before possibly evaluating the right-hand-side of the `||`. If you didn’t include the `await` then the right-hand-side will never be evaluated provided the left-hand-side evaluates to a non-falsy value (regardless or if it’s a `Promise<T>` or not).

Comment: Quoting from the downvote button's tooltip: *"This question does not show any research effort"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial to test.

```js
function getFirstAsync() {
    return new Promise(res => {
        console.log("getFirstAsync");
        res(true);
    });
}

function getSyncAsync() {
    return new Promise(res => {
        console.log("getSyncAsync");
        res(false);
    });
}

(async function () {

    const result = (await getFirstAsync()) || (await getSyncAsync());
    console.log({result});

})();
```

The second function is not called.

Comment: `async function getFirstAsync() {
 console.log('getFirstAsync');
 return true;
}
async function getSecondAsync() {
 console.log('getSecondAsync');
 return false;
}

const result = (await getFirstAsync()) || (await getSecondAsync());` 
Do you know why the code here threw the error on stackoverflow snippet?
The code working on the browser but as copied to the snippet it didn't work, was it because of async/await keyword?